# Inconsistency with FactoMineR's PCA function default data scaling?

Tags: r, pca

I've noticed that performing the principal components analysis with FactoMineR's PCA function gives different results (wrt when I perform PCA "manually") when I tell the function to automatically scale the data with `scale.unit=TRUE`. Here's an example:

```
library("FactoMineR")
library("factoextra")
data("decathlon2")

decathlon_active <- decathlon2[1:23, 1:10]

%% PCA with FactoMineR function
res_pca <- PCA(decathlon_active, scale.unit=TRUE, graph=FALSE)

%% Manual PCA
decathlon_active_scaled <- scale(decathlon_active, center=TRUE, scale=TRUE)
decathlon_active_scaled_cov <- cov(decathlon_active_scaled)
dasc_eig <- eigen(decathlon_active_scaled_cov)
manual_prin_comp <- as.matrix(decathlon_active_scaled) %*% as.matrix(dasc_eig$vectors)

%% PCA with FactoMineR function but with data already scaled
res_pca_2 <- PCA(decathlon_active_scaled, scale.unit=FALSE, graph=FALSE)
```

Here's the results:

**res_pca**

[image]

**manual_prin_comp**

[image]

**res_pca_2**

[image]

So `manual_prin_comp` agrees with `res_pca_2` and they are both different from `res_pca`, why? The problem is in the scaling I think, what's going on?

Comment: I think you just need to add in the `center`s from `res_pca$call$centre` when you `scale()` the data to replicate it with the manual method.

Comment: Also make sure you're projecting into the same number of PCA dimensions. `FactoMineR::PCA()` defaults to `5` dimensions but your manual one will have `10`.

Comment: @DanAdams I thought that both the ```scale()``` function and ```PCA(..., scale.unit=TRUE,...)``` performed z-score scaling on the dataset, why do I need to tweak the input to the ```scale()``` function by adding the ```center```s ? Also... what are these ```center```s ?

Comment: Those centers in `$call$centre` are the `mean()` of each of the input variables in the data.

Comment: Have you tried any of the other principal component functions? I usually use `stats::prcomp()`